# Getting origin url in api controller requested with ajax call

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api, http-headers, asp.net-web-api2, httprequest

I have this call:

```
                            $http({
                                url: 'http://myazurewebsite.azurewebsites.net/api/ValueCall/CheckForExistingValuers',
                                method: "GET",
                                params: { loanID: $scope.loanIdPopup }
                            }).success(function (data) {

                            }).error(function (data) {

                            });
```

We have three different versions of the site utilizing the same codebase. I would like to know how can I know on the API side which URL the request is coming from?

Do I need to add some other values to the actual ajax call which then will be consumed in the api controller?